# Loading VGG16 model in colab notebook (with other TF trained model) failed while loading vgg16 template works perfectly in blank notebook

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on multi class classification products. As data, I have text and image inputs.
As first step I used `Word2Vec` and USE models. No pb. here.

As a second step I load `VGG16` model which generates following message:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:==================================
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'VarIsInitializedOp_113:0' shape=() dtype=bool>
```

Here is code:
`base_model = VGG16()`
`model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=base_model.layers[-2].output)`
`print(model.summary())`

I noticed that running that code in a new notebook works fine (while `VGG16` loading in common notebook failed).

So, what could be the reasons for that strange behavior ? I would be very interesting on how to make things properly,

Thank you for help !